# Validation error when updating acceleration structure (VK_KHR_ray_tracing)

Tags: vulkan

Recently, I added support for the **VK_KHR_ray_tracing** extension in my Vulkan framework with this [tutorial](https://nvpro-samples.github.io/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/) as a template. Unfortunately, it doesn't handle acceleration structure updates.

I figured out that rebuilding is quite similar to first building it. The only difference is setting the update field on *VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR* to *VK_TRUE* and set the src and dst acceleration structures accordingly.
Currently, I use the same VkAccelerationStructureKHR for src and dst, i.e. it is updating itself, which is according to the specification:

> If update is VK_TRUE, the srcAccelerationStructure and dstAccelerationStructure objects must either be the same object or not have any memory aliasing

In my application, the TLAS is rebuilt every frame (dynamic objects) and this works well except for constantly getting a validation error:

> If update is VK_TRUE, srcAccelerationStructure must have been built before with VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_ALLOW_UPDATE_BIT_KHR set in VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR::flags (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.141.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR-update-03538)

However, during debugging, the *VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_ALLOW_UPDATE_BIT_KHR* flag is set on every *vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructureKHR* call.

My best guess is that this is a bug in the vulkan beta drivers of Nvidia (457.33) but there might also be something else wrong which is not caught by the validation layers.

Has anybody experience with the **VK_KHR_ray_tracing** extensions and managed to get acceleration structure updates working without any validation errors?

EDIT:
The linked tutorial also has a sample with animations and TLAS updates, see [here](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR). When running this sample, the same validation error comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use a recent Vulkan SDK version or build the layers yourself. The above validation layer message is probably caused by [this bug in the validation layers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/2066) and not caused by your application. It has been fixed for SDK 1.2.154, which has been released on october.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was still one version behind and the SDK update fixed it!